# Cómo puedo adaptar librerias con constructores (C++) para realizar la misma función pero en C

Tags: c++, c, arduino, stm32

cómo están?, me encuentro buscando la forma de adaptar una librería para arduino la cual está hecha en C++ para usarla con mi IDE, mediante el cual programo microcontroladores en C. La librería es la siguiente:

```
#include "NexObject.h"

NexObject::NexObject(uint8_t pid, uint8_t cid, const char *name)
{
this->__pid = pid;
this->__cid = cid;
this->__name = name;
}

uint8_t NexObject::getObjPid(void)
{
return __pid;
}

uint8_t NexObject::getObjCid(void)
{
return __cid;
}

const char* NexObject::getObjName(void)
{
return __name;
}

void NexObject::printObjInfo(void)
{
dbSerialPrint("[");
dbSerialPrint((uint32_t)this);
dbSerialPrint(":");
dbSerialPrint(__pid);
dbSerialPrint(",");
dbSerialPrint(__cid);
dbSerialPrint(",");
if (__name)
{
dbSerialPrint(__name);
}
else
{
    dbSerialPrint("(null)");
}
    dbSerialPrintln("]");
}
```

Lo que no se es como adaptar los métodos que tienen constructores para hacer el mismo procedimiento pero en C como por ejemplo el NexObject::NexObject(...).

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: Arduino es realmente C++ por debajo. Puedes escribir código con clases y constructores. Todo lo que necesitas es nombrar el archivo con extensión `.cpp`

Comment: @Candid Moe gracias por tu respuesta pero aún así me gustaría saber como hacerlo en puro código C ya que no domino esa parte. Estaba pensando en usar estructuras pero no se si me funcionará

Comment: @Candid Moe la cuestión es que no voy a usar esas librerías con un arduino sino con microcontroladores STM32 y el STM32Cube IDE, ahí al menos hasta donde es mi conocimiento se programa en C, es por eso que pregunto

Comment: Da lo mismo donde lo vas a correr; es C++ igual. Lo único que cambia es el hardware (pines, pwm, adc, ...) Has la prueba.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, lo intentaré y aviso